# Why is my x-value infinite if my position_hint is "x" instead of "left?

Tags: python, kivy, position, kivy-language

In the following kv-code I assign x the value 0.1 and pos_hint["x"] x.

```
ball:
        id: bl_w
        x: 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":self.x, "y":0.4}
        size_hint: .05, .05
        source: "ball.jpg"
```

print(widget.pos_hint) returns {'x': inf, 'y': 0.4} but if I change my kv code to pos_hint: {"left":self.x, "y":0.4}, print(widget.pos_hint) returns {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.4}. Unfortunately, the value is then no longer relative to the screen size, which is why I do not want to use "left" for "pos_hint".

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pos_hint triggers recursive update events, when it's used to position the ball then the ball's `self.x` changes, which triggers the pos_hint to update again, which causes `self.x` to change again, and so on.